# How to repeat an array initiation?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, download, nsmutablearray, plist

```
minecraftArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                 initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.avicode.co.uk/iphone/minepedia/plists/minecraft.plist"]];
```

What I would like to do is everytime the view appears I want the array to redownload the data, at the moment they all redownload when the app is completely closed, (including from multitasking), is there a to force the download again.

Comment: is that all i need to do, would that not give a memory leak, Im using ARC so I can't dealloc it, otherwise I'd do that

Comment: Execute it in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: at the moment viewDidLoad, it doesn't redownload when the view appears, and viewWillAppear doesn't download it at all

Comment: If you're using ARC, then this will not create a memory leak.

Comment: I've tried just calling the code again, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you refreshing the view after downloading?

Comment: Keep in mind that `initWithContentsOfURL` will use the standard browser algorithm for either downloading fresh or using a cached copy.  (A way to circumvent this behavior is to append a unique "tail" to the URL -- something that the other end will ignore.)

Comment: oh right, hmm ok Ill give that a go, im not currently working on it, so whenb I start working again I'll let you know what the outcome it